# How to convert a string to date?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime-format

I have a .csv file with dates formatted as '2020-01-11T00:00:00.000-05:00'. 
When I read the file in python, it recognizes it as an object. 
How can I convert it to a date '2020-01-11' using python?

Comment: Try searching existing posts using your keywords, and look for the answers that have been upvoted the most times. Also, you may want to delete your post entirely as it has been asked before on stackoverflow, and duplicate questions are frowned upon, probably the number 1 faux pas on this site. (take it from me who made this error not a few months ago)  :)

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? There are plenty of resources on the subject, and I see no indication that this question cannot be answered by those.